# How to add and remove a blank space under stampt element

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using BOOTSTRAP and [ISOTOPE](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to make a filtering in group of elements. I have a collapse button (red cell in example) to hide and show filters. My idea is after I open a collapsed filters to get a blank white space under a red cell all the way to the bottom, and instead a 3 green cols they should become to only 2.After I collapse the filters it should become again in 3 green cols. Here is example of my code https://jsfiddle.net/tqLdre3s/2/

```
$stampElem = $('.filter-box');
var $Grid = $('.list-container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.content-box',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  stamp: $stampElem
});
$('.list-container').on( 'click', '.filter-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $Grid.isotope( 'stamp', $stampElem );
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $Grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
$Grid.isotope({ filter: '.start-box-filters' });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/qkdpdva8/)

add this CSS

```
.gigante{height:270px;}
```

JS

```
$stampElem = $('.filter-box');
var $Grid = $('.list-container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.content-box',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    stamp: $stampElem,
    masonry: {
        // columnWidth: ".filter-box"
    }
 });

 $(' a.btn').on( 'click', function() {
 $('.filter-box').toggleClass('gigante');
 // trigger layout after item size changes
 $Grid.isotope('layout');
 });
 $('.list-container').on( 'click', '.filter-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $Grid.isotope( 'stamp', $stampElem );
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $Grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
 });
 $Grid.isotope({ filter: '.start-box-filters' });
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Your solution is not exactly what i want. Your solution is [this](http://s4.postimg.org/vjdkmwhh9/screenshot_jsfiddle_net_2015_11_08_15_31_50.png), my idea was to make look like [this](http://s8.postimg.org/7shlhiv9h/screenshot_jsfiddle_net_2015_11_08_15_31_501.png).

Comment: Not quite how isotope masonry works in your version, but good luck.